# Is this series convergent? $\sum \frac{(\log n)^4}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is this series convergent? (I know it is but how do I show it?)

$$\frac{(\log n)^4}{n^2}$$

I've said that for large enough $n$, $(\log n)^4 < n$.
but that leaves me with

$$\dfrac{(\log n)^4}{n^2}\lt \dfrac{n}{n^2} = \dfrac 1n$$ but $\sum \frac 1n$ is a divergent series, so that doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with $(\log n)^4 < \sqrt{n}$, or some smaller exponent, every positive exponent will do.

Comment: Yeah I'll give it a go, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

Prove/check the following:

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\forall\,\epsilon>0\;,\;\;\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n^\epsilon}=0\\{}\\
\bullet&\;\;\frac{\log^4n}{n^2}\le\frac{\left(n^{1/10}\right)^4}{n^2}=\ldots\end{align*}$$